# Rich Text Editor Image Upload Handler

Tags: asp.net, handler, image-upload, ashx, rte

[Rich Text Editor Image Upload Sample](https://richtexteditor.com/docs/uploadfiles.aspx)

I want to use imageupload handler for rich text editor but I couldn't complete the code.

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="imageupload"%>
using System;
using System.Web;
public class Upload : IHttpHandler{    
    public voidProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
       HttpPostedFile uploads = context.Request.Files["imageupload"];
       string file = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uploads.FileName);
       uploads.SaveAs(context.Server.MapPath(".") + "\\Images\\"+ file);
       string url = "/Images/"+ file;
       ..............
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

Images from Rich Text Editor should be stored on the server as files. I couldn't adapt the code sample I found.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.